# What does "how to identify impulse response of a system?" mean?

Tags: linear-systems, impulse-response

I don't know where to start from, I'm not familiar with math.
I'm trying to understand this question "how to identify impulse response of a system?".

As you can see as below figure, as I know, the input delta function and output is $h[n]$.

[image]

In this case, if I put impulse (function) signal in to above system, then I can get the impulse response. Then I think the output $h[n]$ and impulse response are the same, doesn't it?

- Question 1: What is the meaning of "how to identify impulse response of a system"? Is this asking about convolution or auocorrelation? I can't understand what it does  mean.
- Question 2: I want to know how to identify impulse response of a system?
- Question 3: Why do we get the output of $y[n]$ when if we know that input $x[n]$, impulse response $h[n]$. I mean the output $y[n]$ is the same $h[n]$ isn't it? I'm very confused.

If you have any hint, please let me know.

**Update**

I found a question in my case as below,

> 1.2.8 Consider a discrete-time LTI system described by the rule $$y(n)=x(n-5)+\frac 12 x(n-7).$$  What is the impulse response $h(n)$
>   of the system ?

How to identify $h[n]$?

the answer :

$h[5]$ = 1+ 0 = 1

$h[7]$ = 0 + 1/2 = 1/2

. . .

Comment: @Laurent Duval Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a system, one often wants to be able to predict the output $y$, given an input $x$. This amounts to identifying a mathematical relation between all inputs and outputs, optimaly as $y = S(x)$. This can be a difficult task in general.

When the system is linear, and time-invariant (its properties do not change over time), then it is proven that it  suffices to know the system's response to a discrete unit pulse $\delta$, to be able to compute the output for any other input $x$, in the form of a convolution equation.

So suppose that your system outputs $h[n]$ when you input $\delta[n]$, then for any $x[n]$, the output will be:
$$y[n] = \sum_k x[k]h[n-k]\,.$$

To identify the impulse response of the system, you ought to provide the numbers, or a generic formula, that give the value for each $h[n]$.

You can try some exercices in [Exercises in Signals, Systems, and Transforms](http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/EL6113/Signals_Exercises.pdf), for  instance 1.2.4 and 1.2.7. You can also check the applet in the [joy of convolution](http://pages.jh.edu/~signals/discreteconv2/).

Since, in practice, it is impossible to generate a discrete pulse, there are other practical identification techniques for real-life systems, using random sequences or sine waves.

Comment: I have updated with one question. Would you help me any hint please ?

Comment: Can you provide us with the first steps of your reasoning, based on the information you have already received

Comment: Basically, I know to get the output of y[n]. most textbook show that how to get y[n] (how to convolution). but this question is a quite difficult to me.

Comment: So input $\delta$ in your system, as it were the $x$ in your new equation, and evaluate the $y$

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Please write the equation from 1.2.8 replacing $x$ by $\delta$, and take for instance $n=5$. What is the value of $y[5]$ then (forget about convolution for the moment, do simple things)?

Comment: Sir, I think I found the answer. then what next? and Can we determine whether IIR or FIR from the results?

Comment: Indeed! Do you have a finite or a infinite number of no-zero coeffcients in the impulse response?

Comment: Sir I think the equation is FIR. because the finite number of non-zero coefficients in the impulse response. am i right? is there any specific name or calling this to find  what i did?

Comment: FIR, perfect. I do not understand your second question

Comment: i wonder that what is this calling what i did (to find FIR), is this having any specific name likely " finding FIR" or anything? I want to know this because when I meet expert, I want to tell this as expert words

Comment: I am not fully sure there is a specific term for it, this is a subset of filter identification. Some may call it "[filter class identification](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/isfir.html?refresh=true)" or "filter type identification".

Comment: By the way, you can improve your skills with the related question [Is this system an FIR filter or an IIR filter?](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8282/is-this-system-an-fir-filter-or-an-iir-filter)

Comment: Thanks Sir. it's very good related question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The operation of linear time invariant system on a signal $f[n]$ can be described as a convolution, e.g.

$$(f \ast h)[n] = g[n]$$

where $g[n]$ is the output and $h[n]$ is convolution filter representing the system.

It is called the impulse response because if you feed in the impulse signal you get the convolution filter as the output, e.g.

$$(\delta \ast h)[n] = h[n]$$

So once you know the impulse response, you can calculate the response to any signal using the first equation.

Comment: Thanks can you tell me why not use the correlation ? I think the same both mechanisms except for time reversal.

Comment: @sogood They are very similar (see http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/what-is-the-difference-between-convolution-and-cross-correlation).     However, a convolution is just a multiplication in the Fourier domain, where as correlation is multiplication by the conjugate. I guess alot of filtering is done in the Fourier domain so the former is easier. Interestingly, the wavelet literature uses correlation, even for wavelets defined in the Fourier domain.

Comment: I almost got it what you mean. you mean that x[n](input) * h[n](impulse response) = y[n](output).  then how to identify impulse response of a system ? is there any way ?

Comment: if you know y[n], you can then go to the frequency domain and do Y[w]/DFT(impulse) which is 1 and get H(w), then you go again in to the discrete time domain and get h[n]. Have a look to this examples in Matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55885-dft-h--n- and http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55822-low-pass-filtering

Comment: @BehindTheSciences Thanks but I don't understand it,  how to go from y[n] to frequency domain? Also can you tell me how to identify the impulse response of a system?

Comment: using the frequency domain is one way that I thought it would be useful if you know about the Fourier Transform: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform  if not, just convolve your input, x[n] with the impulse delta[n]: have a look to the discrete time domain here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTI_system_theory